# Is it normal that network-manager manages virbr0?

Tags: networking, network-manager, virtualization

I recently upgraded to vivid (I know it's still WIP), and have found that network-manager shows an interface `virbr0` as Connected.

[image]

virbr0 is an interface added by libvirt to handle networking between virtual machines and host system. I feel network-manager should not mess with this, but I'm quite unsure about this.

Here is a doc on the subject, but I couldn't figure out if this is a bug in NM or not: http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking

EDIT: I opened this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1432599

Comment: As you know that Vivid is a WIP, you should use Launchpad to file a bug so that the developers are aware of this issue, not use Ask Ubuntu...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby in fact I did (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1432599) but as I'm unsure if it's really a bug, I'm trying to sort it out to avoid bothering devs with a potentially false issue.

Comment: This sounds like an issue or a discussion that belongs on the NetworkManager mailing list.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I asked the question on the NetworkManager list, and they mainly suggested to upgrade to NM 1.0 or later...